# Why is static_cast used in QT's official document

Tags: c++, qt, events, dynamic-cast, static-cast

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html

In QT's offical document, static_cast is used in code like

```
QKeyEvent *ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
...
MyCustomEvent *myEvent = static_cast<MyCustomEvent *>(event);
```

However in my experience, dynamic_cast should be used since this is a cast from base to derived 
Is there any special reason for the static_cast use?

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly alright to use `static_cast` if you are absolutely certain that the appropriate `dynamic_cast` would succeed. Using `static_cast` is faster than `dynamic_cast` since it involves no runtime checks.

Comment: Also ```dynamic_cast``` requires RTTI to be enabled which is not always wanted.

Answer (score 3):

The code you see in that Qt documentation is valid. Using `static_cast` may be used and replaces `dynamic_cast` only if you know for sure that the pointer you want to cast from points to the object of class you want to cast to. In your question you omit very important detail. Before performing `static_cast` it checks for the type:

```
if (event->type() == MyCustomEventType) {...}
```